# AWS SDK - getObject convert returned file from ASCII buffer to gzip and then to csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

I'm using the aws-sdk for Nodejs, and I'm getting an object back from AWS bucket in the form of a buffer, like so: [31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0 ....]

The file is gzip with a csv inside, `filename.csv.gz`

How can I convert the buffer and simply read the file and parse the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zlib` library can gunzip a buffer so you should be able to use that to unzip the buffer `Body` property of the data parameter of the callback from the s3 `getObject` function:

```
const zlib = require("zlib")
zlib.gunzip(data.Body, function(err, csvFileBuffer) {
//process CSV file
})
```

This then means that csvFileBuffer is a buffer of your csv file. You could then read that into a string with `csvFileBuffer.toString('utf8')` or read it some other way to actually process the CSV file